# Why do I need to add "[0]" to my data to get it to render, if I don't, there is an error?

Tags: html, json, fetch

I am currently learning JSON and there is something I can't seem to understand, I am hoping somebody out there can clear it up for me.

I am using the breaking bad API as a starter point:

https://breakingbadapi.com/documentation

I am pulling all of the info into a  dropdown and using the char_id as an identifier. Once a person is selected, it is passed to a FETCH function which will in turn, display the data.

Something I don't understand though, is when I am assigning the data to variables, I have to use "data[0].name" instead of just [data.name] even though the data is already selected?

For e.g, If I select Walter White who has a char_id of 1. https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/**1** will be passed and his info will display.

However, instead of just using [data.name], I have to use [data[0].name]. Even though his char_id is NOT 0. if I don't include it, I get an error.

Could somebody explain this to me?

HTML

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="dropdown">
      <select id="characters" onchange="getInfo(this.value)"></select>
    </div>
    <div id="characterInfo"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const characterInfo_div = document.querySelector("#characterInfo");
const dropdown = document.querySelector("#characters");
let i = 0;

function getInfo(character) {
  console.log(character);
  
  fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/" + character)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    characterInfo_div.innerHTML=
     "<p> Name:" + [data[0].name] + "</p>" +
      "<p> Birthday:" + [data[0].birthday] + "</p>" +
      "<p> Status:" + [data[0].status] + "</p>" +
      "<p> Nickname:" + [data[0].nickname] + "</p>" +
      "<img src='" + [data[0].img] + "'/>"
    });
};

fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      dropdown.innerHTML+= "<option value=" + [data[i].char_id] + ">" + [data[i].name] + "</option>"
    }
    });
```

**EDIT:
Based on somebodys answer about it being in an array, I have updated it to take away the brackets but now it is rendering "undefined", any ideas?**

JS

```
function getInfo(character) {
  console.log(character);
  
  fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/" + character)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    characterInfo_div.innerHTML=
     "<p> Name:" + data.name + "</p>" +
      "<p> Birthday:" + data.birthday + "</p>" +
      "<p> Status:" + data.status + "</p>" +
      "<p> Nickname:" + data.nickname + "</p>" +
      "<img src='" + data.img + "'/>"
    });
};

fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      dropdown.innerHTML+= "<option value=" + data[i].char_id + ">" + data[i].name + "</option>"
    }
    });
```

Comment: I don’t think that answer was the correct fix, but I think it is *one* fix. When you say rendering undefined, is the drop down saying undefined or the p tags like Nickname? 

I think you need to do a console.log(data) right before creating the p tags and see what type of variable data is.

Comment: I saw the previous answer and I'm not sure you did what was suggested. It took away the *outer* brackets, but it looks like you removed the outer brackets *and* the `[0]` on each element. It all depends on the data. Try with the `[0]` put back in.

Comment: the p tags. The dropdown is working fine. If I console log(data) when a character is selected, it shows up perfectly fine in console. I can't access any of it though with things like data.name or data.birthday, it just shows as undefined

Comment: Seems putting [0] back in worked. I understand it all completely now, thanks again!

Comment: Based on the API documentation it shouldn't return an array, but apparently for you it does. What's the exact url you are fetching? Even though it's not described in the docs, maybe adding an array of ids to the url might result into the server trying to return objects for all ids in that array (even though that's quite unlikely).

Comment: I overlooked something in the answer, so that might be completely wrong. Yet it might be the root cause of the API returning an array.

Comment: The data is returned as an array with a length of 1. E.g `[{/*Some Stuff*/}]` .This is why you need to reference the first object in the array. The documentation is a little out in that regard. I looked at the actual response in the browser.

Comment: Also if you look at the end point name `/api/characters` , note it is plural. The endpoint returns an array of  characters based on further rout info or query string parameters. When a single integer is supplied as the next route segment an array of one character is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sample URL - perhaps https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/2 and paste it in the address bar of the browser, you'll see the response

```
[{"char_id":2,"name":"Jesse Pinkman","birthday":"09-24-1984","occupation":["Meth Dealer"],"img":"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/breakingbad/images/9/95/JesseS5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120620012441","status":"Alive","nickname":"Cap n' Cook","appearance":[1,2,3,4,5],"portrayed":"Aaron Paul","category":"Breaking Bad","better_call_saul_appearance":[]}]
```

The outer brackets (`[]`) indicate that the data is an array. The braces (`{}`) inside the brackets enclose the objects which are the elements of the array.

`data[0]` means the first element of the array, which is an object. `.name` is the property of the object which contains the name.

So you would read it as,

> the name property of the first element in the data array